# Create xcframework for iOS with Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, xcframework

I want to know:

- it's possible to create an ios xcframework without flutter references as flutterEngine or platformView?
  Ex: Expose Classes and Methods created on Dart and use them on Swift.

Official docs said

> Create frameworks for your compiled Dart code and all Flutter plugins. Use CocoaPods for the Flutter engine. With this option, embed the frameworks for your application and the plugins in Xcode, but distribute the Flutter engine as a CocoaPods podspec.

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

- Can I pass a WIDGET (dart) as UIVIEW (not viewController, only view) to put it as part of my custom view?
  Platform views let pass from UIVIEW to WIDGET but I want inverse relation.

SOURCE: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/platform-views

I don't find on docs how to do it if it's possible. I appreciate any docs or examples.